# Injecting class to another class whose instance is created manually

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, cdi

I have a scenario, where I have one Utility class which is Singleton and I need to inject it to another class which does not have any annotation at class level.

How can I inject it to this class ?

@EJB or @Inject is not working since the class in which I am using @EJB/@Inject is creating using getInstance() method.

Comment: Could you please update your question with the code of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: What container and version are you using? If CDI 1.2, you could use the CDI utility class to programmatically look up the reference.

Comment: I am using Jboss EAP 6

Comment: Do you have to use `getInstance` to retrieve the class, instead of just injecting it?

Comment: @JohnAment, I think the OP is trying to inject a `@Singleton` into a class that was implemented using the [Singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#Lazy_initialization). Shouldn't the OP use **only** one approach or the other? Like, have both elements as `@Singleton` or have both implemented according to the "plain old" Singleton pattern?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use @Inject or @EJB in a POJO, but you can make a classic local lookup.

e.g. Supposing the EJB implements the local interface *IServiceBeanLocal*, which contains the methods you are interested in:

```
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

public class Utility {

    private static IServiceBeanLocal service;

    try {
        InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
        service = (IServiceBeanLocal) ic.lookup(ejbJndiName);

        // or simply
        // service = (IServiceBeanLocal) InitialContext.doLookup(ejbJndiName);

        service.method(); // invoke the desired method

    } catch (NamingException e) {
        logger.error("Lookup exception:", e);
    }
}
```

*ejbJndiName* depends on the packaging of your EJB, but must be something like:

```
java:global/app_name/module_name/EJBClass!com.local.interface.path.IServiceBeanLocal
```

Hope it helps.